# Unable to retrieve complete text from an element using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am trying to retrieve text in  using unmarshalling example of JAXB but unable to retrieve the within ... tag. This is my first question and hence quite unsure on indenting my code, but here it goes : 
LangFlag.java

```
    package IDJAXBParser;

    import java.util.List;

    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAnyElement;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;



    @XmlType( propOrder = { "name", "description", "match", "context" } )
    @XmlRootElement( name = "langFlag" )

    public class LangFlag
    {

        String name;

        public String getName()
        {
            return name;
        }

        @XmlAttribute( name = "name" )
        public void setName( String name )
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

        String description;

        public String getDescription()
        {
            return description;
        }

        @XmlElement( name = "description" )
        public void setDescription( String description )
        {
            this.description = description;
        }

        String context;

        @XmlAnyElement(BioHandler.class)
        public String getContext()
        {
            return context;
        }


        public void setContext( String context )
        {
            this.context = context;
        }
        List<String> match;

        public List<String> getMatch()
        {
            return match;
        }

        @XmlElement( name = "match" )
        public void setMatch( List<String> match )
        {
            this.match = match;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer( "Name: " + getName() + "\n" );
           str.append("Description:" + getDescription() + "\n");
           str.append("Context:" + getContext() + "\n");
           str.append("Match:" + getMatch() + "\n");
           str.append("\n");
            return str.toString();
        }
    }
```

ListOfLangFlags.java

```
    package IDJAXBParser;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

    @XmlRootElement( name = "listOfLangFlags" )
    public class ListOfLangFlags
    {
        List<LangFlag> listOfLangFlags;

        public List<LangFlag> getLangFlags()
        {
            return listOfLangFlags;
        }

        /**
         * element that is going to be marshaled in the xml
         */
        @XmlElement( name = "langFlag" )
        public void setLangFlags( List<LangFlag> listOfLangFlags )
        {
            this.listOfLangFlags = listOfLangFlags;
        }

        public void add( LangFlag langFlag )
        {
            if( this.listOfLangFlags == null )
            {
                this.listOfLangFlags = new ArrayList<LangFlag>();
            }
            this.listOfLangFlags.add( langFlag );

        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
            for( LangFlag langFlag : this.listOfLangFlags )
            {
                str.append( langFlag.toString() );
            }
            return str.toString();
        }

    }
```

UnMarshalJAXVBComplete.java
        package IDJAXBParser;

```
    import java.io.File;

    import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
    import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
    import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

    import IDJAXBParser.ListOfLangFlags;

    public class UnMarshalJAXVBComplete
    {
        public static void main( String[] args )
        {

            try
            {

                File file = new File( "testv1.xml" );
                JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance( ListOfLangFlags.class );

                Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
                ListOfLangFlags langFlags = (ListOfLangFlags)jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal( file );
                System.out.println( langFlags );

            }
            catch( JAXBException e )
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
```

This is my XML document :

```
<listOfLangFlags>
<langFlag name="Lang Flag Name">
                                <description>Lang Flag Description</description>
                                <context begin="0" end="100">I am so <span class="locality">blue </span>
                                I'm greener than purple. </context>
                                <suggestions/>
                                <match>I am so</match>
                                <match>blue</match>
                            </langFlag>
        </listOfLangFlags>
```

BioHandler.java

```
package IDJAXBParser;

import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;

import javax.xml.bind.ValidationEventHandler;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.DomHandler;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class BioHandler implements DomHandler<String, StreamResult> {

    private static final String BIO_START_TAG = "<context>";
    private static final String BIO_END_TAG = "</context>";

    private StringWriter xmlWriter = new StringWriter();

    public StreamResult createUnmarshaller(ValidationEventHandler errorHandler) {
        xmlWriter.getBuffer().setLength(0);
        return new StreamResult(xmlWriter);
    }

    public String getElement(StreamResult rt) {
        String xml = rt.getWriter().toString();
        int beginIndex = xml.indexOf(BIO_START_TAG) + BIO_START_TAG.length();
        int endIndex = xml.indexOf(BIO_END_TAG);
        return xml.substring(beginIndex, endIndex);
    }

    public Source marshal(String n, ValidationEventHandler errorHandler) {
        try {
            String xml = BIO_START_TAG + n.trim() + BIO_END_TAG;
            StringReader xmlReader = new StringReader(xml);
            return new StreamSource(xmlReader);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: This is the result of my code :
Name: Lang Flag Name
Description:Lang Flag Description
Context:
      I'm greener than purple. 
Match:[I am so, blue]

Comment: what's your expected result? BTW, please also post the source code of `BioHandler.java`, since you specify`@XmlAnyElement(BioHandler.class)`.

Comment: @bekyang, the expected result is I get back the entire text from the context field i.e. I am so blue I'm greener than purple.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `DomHandler` implementation which convert between `DOM object` and `String`.

```
import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.xml.bind.ValidationEventHandler;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.DomHandler;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.DocumentFragment;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class BioHandler implements DomHandler<String, DOMResult> {

    private StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

    public DOMResult createUnmarshaller(ValidationEventHandler errorHandler) {
        return new DOMResult();
    }

    public String getElement(DOMResult rt) {
        Node n = rt.getNode();
        Element ele = null;
        if (n instanceof Document) {
            ele = ((Document)n).getDocumentElement();
        } else if (n instanceof DocumentFragment) {
            ele = (Element)n.getChildNodes().item(0);
        }
        //StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); //only capture the text under current node.
        if (ele != null && "context".equals(ele.getLocalName())) {
            try {
                NodeList nl = (NodeList)XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath()
                        .compile("descendant::text()").evaluate(ele, XPathConstants.NODESET);
                int length = nl.getLength();
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    buffer.append(nl.item(i).getTextContent());
                }
            } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
//for problem tracing
//System.err.println("BioHandler.getElement(), ele="+ele.getLocalName() +", result=["+result+"]");
        return buffer.toString();
    }

    public Source marshal(String n, ValidationEventHandler errorHandler) {
        try {
            String xml = "<context>" + n.trim() + "</context>";
            StringReader xmlReader = new StringReader(xml);
            return new StreamSource(xmlReader);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

During my testing, the unknown `<suggestions/> element` is handled by the same object. So I declare `buffer` as class variable and output captured content every time.

Comment: its working fine with a single node in the xml but when I add another node, the context text is added to the next context. How do I reset the buffer? Thanks

Comment: A solution is moving variable `buffer` into `getElement(DOMResult rt)` method. You should also consider about the return value when `ele` is null.

Comment: I tried moving the variable buffer into the getElement(DOMResult rt) method. But this cleared all the "Text" context element.

Comment: It could be the problem of `<suggestions/>` as I mentioned in the answer. Can you remove it from xml file and try again?

Comment: Im still getting the same result i.e. an empty string

Comment: I modify the code in the answer. The `System.err.println...` could help you tracing where the problem is. I believe the `context` is overwrited when JAXP convert other XML elements.